# How can I update a column in a table after there has been an update to another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I have a table called orders that has an id column. Then I have order_lines which has a column called order_id to reference back to orders and it also has a product_id column to reference to another table called products where pricing info lives.

I want to have it so the orders subtotal field is automatically calculated to get the sum of all the product prices * the quantity from order_lines and products. I am attempting to create a trigger in SQLite to do this, but I keep getting errors.

This gives me a syntax error near "END":

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tSubTotal
AFTER
UPDATE OF quantity
    ON order_lines 
    BEGIN
UPDATE
    o
SET
    subtotal = (
        select
            SUM(p.price * ol.quantity) as subtotal
        from
            order_lines ol
            join products p on ol.product_id = p.id
        where
            ol.order_id = i.id
    )
FROM
    inserted i
    INNER JOIN orders o ON o.id = i.id
END;
```

However, this query alone does pull the data I want when a order id is specified:

```sql
select
            SUM(p.price * ol.quantity) as subtotal
        from
            order_lines ol
            join products p on ol.product_id = p.id
        where
            ol.order_id = 1
```

UPDATE:
I ended up creating a trigger that will calculate the total price of each order_line, but now I want to create another one to sum the total_price to update the subtotal on orders.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tTotalPrice
UPDATE
ON order_lines
BEGIN
UPDATE order_lines
    SET total_price = 
        (NEW.quantity) *
                   (SELECT p.price FROM products p WHERE p.id = order_lines.product_id)
    WHERE order_lines.id = NEW.id;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, I would expect trigger logic like this:

```
UPDATE orders o
    SET subtotal = (NEW.quantity - OLD.quantity) *
                   (SELECT p.price FROM products WHERE p.id = ol.product_id)
    WHERE o.id = NEW.order_id;
```

Much of your code has little to do with SQLite.

Comment: I modeled my code after the documentation here: https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html. Yours doesn't look like a full trigger to me

Comment: @Cole . . . This isn't a full trigger.  This is the logic for the body of the trigger.

Comment: Right, but that query isn't connecting to the order_lines table at all so the trigger would always fail because it doesn't recognize those fields

Comment: I ended up updating mine using the NEW operator you mentioned, but it still isn't exactly perfect.
CREATE TRIGGER tSubtotal
UPDATE
ON order_lines
BEGIN
UPDATE orders
    SET subtotal = (SELECT SUM(p.price * ol.quantity)
        from
            order_lines ol
            join products p on ol.product_id = p.id
        where
            ol.order_id = NEW.order_id
    )
    WHERE orders.id = NEW.order_id;
END

Comment: I ended up creating a trigger that will calculate the total price of each order_line, but now I want to create another one to sum the total_price to update the subtotal on orders.
CREATE TRIGGER tTotalPrice
UPDATE
ON order_lines
BEGIN
UPDATE order_lines
    SET total_price = 
        (NEW.quantity) *
                   (SELECT p.price FROM products p WHERE p.id = order_lines.product_id)
    WHERE order_lines.id = NEW.id;
END;

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get two triggers created that work. One updates the total_price in order_lines and the other would update the subtotal in orders after the first trigger runs.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tTotalPrice
UPDATE
ON order_lines
BEGIN
UPDATE order_lines
    SET total_price = 
        (NEW.quantity) *
                   (SELECT p.price FROM products p WHERE p.id = order_lines.product_id)
    WHERE order_lines.id = NEW.id;
END;
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tSubtotal
AFTER UPDATE
ON order_lines
BEGIN
UPDATE orders
    SET subtotal =  (select sum(total_price) from order_lines ol where order_id = NEW.order_id)
    WHERE orders.id = NEW.order_id;
END
```